# Var is undefined in foundation.util.touch.js

Tags: javascript, ipad, zurb-foundation

I am getting an error on mobile when trying to use the sliders and the slider isn't draggable.  This is for the non-native version. The sliders work on desktops (chrome, firefox, ie) but not on an ipad (safari)

Foundation 6.5.3 via Foundation Rails 6.5.3

error in console is:

> TypeError: touches is undefined on line 133 foundation.util.touch.js

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.util.touch.js#L133

```
 var touches = event.changedTouches,
          first = touches[0],
          eventTypes = {
            touchstart: 'mousedown',
            touchmove: 'mousemove',
            touchend: 'mouseup'
          },
          type = eventTypes[event.type],
          simulatedEvent
;
```

133 is this line:

```
first = touches[0],
```

Is it valid to use one var in a multi-var declaration var statement like that, declaring it and then using it in the same statement? Is that what the problem is?

Comment: It is valid. So it looks like the `event.changedTouches` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem occurs when using older versions of jQuery. See https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/11763